# Where to create methods in classes

Tags: c#

Below I am trying to create a method that returns a list filled with Five integers, based on userInput. I want to make methods to use inside that method.
Where would I create these methods in the class, to have scope of variables and then use them inside the main method that returns a list?

```
class UserLists
{                
    public static List<int> UserFiveList()
    {
        List<int> userList = new List<int>();
        int userPick1 = 0;
        int userPick2 = 0;
        int userPick3 = 0;
        int userPick4 = 0;
        int userPick5 = 0;


        // method that fills the list
        void FillUserFiveList(int pick, int count)
        {

            do
            {
                Console.Write("Enter first number between 1-45 : ");
                pick = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                if (userList.Contains(pick))
                    Console.WriteLine("You have to enter a unique number");

                else if (pick >= 1 && pick <= 45)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Adding your first number in the list...");
                    userList.Add(pick);
                }
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("You have to enter a number between 1-45");
            } while (userList.Count < count);
        }

        //end of method

        FillUserFiveList(userPick1, 1);

        FillUserFiveList(userPick2, 2);

        FillUserFiveList(userPick3, 3);

        FillUserFiveList(userPick4, 4);

        FillUserFiveList(userPick5, 5);

        return userList;
    }
    public static List<int> UserOneList()
    {
        List<int> userOneList = new List<int>();
        do
        {
            Console.Write("Enter your number between 1-20 : ");
            int userPick1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (userPick1 >= 1 && userPick1 <= 20)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Adding your only number in the list...");
                userOneList.Add(userPick1);
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("You have to enter a number between 1-20");
        } while (userOneList.Count < 1);
        return userOneList;
    }
}
```

Comment: With that general lack of understanding of C#, it seems to me that you're asking for a tutorial. Such questions are off-topic here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: functions and methods should be placed at the same place, i.e. right inside the class, not inside other functions/methods

Comment: @Rafalon some [cool C#7 stuff](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions) to confuse us all ;) I am still trying to figure out what advantage this might bring

Comment: @MongZhu still interesting to know, thanks. This could bring the advantage of not having to pass local variables to private functions for example. In OP's code, he would need to pass `userList` for every call, but with local function he doesn't have to

Comment: @Rafalon wouldn't you solve it with a delegate and lambda. was there before C#7 and had the same amount of code

Comment: @MongZhu Right, but delegates and lambdas are still hard-*er* to read for many developpers out there

Comment: @Rafalon granted. that might be true. If I ever meet a usecase where I actually use this nested method functionality I buy you a beer! ;) cheers mate